# No video output when accessing the BIOS after upgrading from Windows 10 to 11

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, windows-11, gpu

I was having a hard time enabling the TPM on my computer so I could upgrade to Windows 11. I left it with a technician who managed to enable it and install Windows 11 but he said he had to update the bios to do so. After updating the bios, my computer simply stopped giving video output to my GPU, he managed to install windows 11 by installing a spare GPU that he had laying around, which he swapped back to mine before handing back my computer.

After the computer is booted I do get a regular output, but if I try to boot to the bios nothing shows up. What could be happening and how could I fix this?

These are my computer specs:

- GPU: NVidia RTX 3060 ti
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 36000
- Motherboard: ASRock B550 Pro 4
- Current bios: American Megatrends International, LLC. P2.10, 02/08/2021

Comment: What was your previous BIOS and what is the new one?

Comment: I've added the current Bios, but I don't know how to check what was the previous one, do you know how I could do that?

Comment: Disable hibernation is what I do.

Answer (score 1):

There are more recent BIOS versions at
[ASRock](https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/B550%20Pro4/index.asp#BIOS)
which might correct the problem. I have no idea why that person chose to
install an old version.

See
[ASRock BIOS Upgrade Instruction](https://www.asrock.com/support/BIOSIG.asp?cat=BIOS10)
on how to update the BIOS.

Be very careful, since an error during the BIOS installation can
brick your computer. If worried, get help from a person that is
more comfortable with the process.